# Scaling several elements according to screen size

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a tactics board for my robotics match. The said board contains a bacground ( `<img src="board.jpg" style="width:100%; height: relative"></img>`) and several other parts that the user can move around with buttons. However, I would like to scale this to phone size. The background does, but the elements do not. I cannot set the elements to a % height, as they are layed out with a `margin-top` and `margin-left`, so a smaller element would not make a difference.

How can I set it so all elements, as well as the margins they are at, reduce and increase according to screen size.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vw` and `vh` units in the style of your elements and it will size them based of the viewport.

```css
element {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 50vw;
}
```

Works on all modern platforms.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Thanks for that. Just had a question - does this work with margin as well? I.e. margin-top = 50vh?

Comment: Yes, and should also work with `calc(50vh - 10rem)` too